# apt-get not working for some reason?

Tags: apt, 16.10

I tried updated apt-get on my Ubuntu system due to some issues

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But it gives me this error

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety InRelease       
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                    
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried some of the solutions given for 'Releases not found' but none of them seem to work. Not sure how to solve this. Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is no longer supported.

Comment: Actually, I have Ubuntu 16.10 on my system

Comment: Settings -> Software & Updates -> Choose Server  then pick a different server ... possibly the current server is not getting connectivity

Comment: @DanielIsaac You are right, thanks for the correction. 17.04 was obviously ZZ - Zesty Zapus.

Comment: @ScottStensland You were absolutely right!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DanielIsaac 16.10 EOL too in 2017: https://askubuntu.com/a/999690