# Ubuntu 16.10 Update problem (some repository yakkety release does not have Release )

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

There are similar messages ("Ubuntu repository does not have a Release file" ... but none works for me).

I try to update a system (apt-get update), but I got some errors.

Concretely (main error):
[CODE]
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does not have a Release file.
[/CODE]

My Ubuntu version:
Description: Ubuntu 16.10
Codename: yakkety

I tried a lot of solutions found in different threads and different sources, such as :
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update

I disabled all PPA's from "Other software" of "Software and Updates" (just in case..).

And also, I commented a pair of lines of sources.list file (just to try):

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner

... but the main error remains (see "main error" on top) ...

When I try to : sudo apt-get update

I got this :

```
...
Ign:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe amd64     Packages
Ign:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe all     Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/yakkety-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 (released 2016.October) had a 9 month life as its NOT a long-term-support (non-LTS) Ubuntu. Its life is over, and upgrades were offered to jump to 17.04 (which now too is post-EOL).  If you don't want a short-term release, or don't like release-upgrading every nine-months - use a LTS release (even numbered years april release only), otherwise accept the offers to release-upgrade.  Backup your data (to be safe) then install a supported version of Ubuntu (as your release-upgrade paths are gone).  New installs your keep your data unless you wrongly select 'format' etc, so backup!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 22):

Ubuntu 16.10 is EOL since July 20, 2017.

Change `http://archive` to `http://old-releases` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

again.

And then update to a supported version.

Comment: Removed the archive from the software and updates => other softwares and then it worked fine.